# Moodle: Dynamic role assignment based on quiz result

Tags: plugins, moodle

is it possible to perform a dynamic role assignment based on a quiz result in Moodle?

How it should work:
- a new user answers the questions in a special "startup" quiz
- based on the result, the user is granted some kind of mentor role

Is this possible with existing Moodle plugins or would I have to implement it by myself?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible with the standard tools, but you could write a small [local plugin](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Local_plugins) that had a cron job which would scan the quiz results and assign a role based on the criteria you set.